# What is the source of the story of the Jewish Soldier who during the Revolutionary War inspired George Washington by lighting his Menorah?

Tags: story-identification, menorah--in-temple, jewish-american-history

What is the source of the story of the Jewish Soldier who during the Revolutionary War inspired George Washington by lighting his Menorah? Also who is the soldier who was in this story, and did George Washington actually give him a medal that was engraved with a Menorah on it?

Comment: Where did you hear this story?  I don't recognize it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Perhaps this book? https://www.amazon.com/Hanukkah-Valley-Forge-Stephen-Krensky/dp/0525477381

Comment: @MonicaCelliohttp://www.beliefnet.com/columnists/virtualtalmud/2007/12/the-truth-about-george-washing.html

Comment: There's a great multi-post investigation starting at http://boston1775.blogspot.com/2007/02/legend-of-hanukkah-at-valley-forge.html